# Encounter error when launched by Spring but not in Postgresql Sql Editor

Tags: spring, postgresql, spring-mvc

My project runs this code :

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public List<Object[]> findAllHistoriqueDureeConnexionsPagination(int first, int max, HistoriqueDureeConnexionSearchDTO search) {
        Session session = getSession();
        String sql = "select TRIM(e.nomemploye) || CASE WHEN e.nomemploye IS NULL OR TRIM(e.nomemploye) = '' THEN '' ELSE ' ' END || e.prenomemploye as user, " + 
                "to_char(h.connexion, 'HH24:MI:SS') as connexion, " + 
                "to_char(h.deconnexion, 'HH24:MI:SS') as deconnexion, " + 
                "to_char((h.duree_seconde || ' second')::interval, 'HH24:MI:SS') as duree, " + 
                "to_char((SUM(h.duree_seconde) OVER (PARTITION BY h.connexion::date) || ' second')::interval, 'HH24:MI:SS') duree_totale_par_date " + 
                "from employe e join utilisateur u on e.idemploye = u.idemploye " +
                "join histodureeconnexion h on h.iduser = u.idutilisateur " +
                "where 1=1 ";
        if (search.getNom() != null && !search.getNom().trim().equals("")) {
            sql += "and lower(e.nomemploye) like :nomemploye ";
        }
        if (search.getPrenom() != null && !search.getPrenom().trim().equals("")) {
            sql += "and lower(e.prenomemploye) like :prenomemploye ";
        }
        
        sql += "order by e.nomemploye, e.prenomemploye, h.connexion";
        SQLQuery<?> s = (SQLQuery<?>) session.createSQLQuery(sql).setFirstResult(first).setMaxResults(max);
        if (search.getNom() != null && !search.getNom().trim().equals("")) {
            s.setParameter("nomemploye", "%"+search.getNom().toLowerCase()+"%");
        }
        if (search.getPrenom() != null && !search.getPrenom().trim().equals("")) {
            s.setParameter("prenomemploye", "%"+search.getPrenom().toLowerCase()+"%");
        }
        
        List<Object[]> l = (List<Object[]>) s.getResultList();
        return l;
    }
```

When I execute the query in the sql variable in Postgresql Sql Editor then it returns results successfully , but when the app is run then I got error :

```
GRAVE: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcher] in context with path [/WorkTools] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet] with root cause
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERREUR: erreur de syntaxe sur ou près de « : »
```

In the `pom.xml` there is this properties config :

```
<postgresql.version>42.2.18</postgresql.version>
```

And the database postgresql version is :

```
postgres -V
postgres (PostgreSQL) 13.1
```

So what is wrong ?

Comment: JPA can't cope with the `::` operator. Try using `cast(.... as interval)` instead (or use `make_interval(seconds => ...)` which wouldn't require a cast to begin with.

Comment: so even if `createSQLQuery` is used then JPA is still called ?